# Xamarin.Forms Previewer

Tags: xamarin.forms

It is really not practical to write a Xamarin.Forms application without a UI previewer. All platforms offer a design preview option, especially if the code needs to be compiled. As far as I know, currently Xamarin only released a previewer for Xamarin Studio for Mac in its alpha channel, which we can't even use in Visual Studio. Why is it that Xamarin still does not provide a previewer? We should not be forced to use a third party tool for this process. (And even the third party tools are in their beta releases.)

Shouldn't there be at least a roadmap or a planned date announced since it is such a fundamental part of the product? It would be nice if someone from Xamarin would answer.

Comment: What is your programming question that you want us to try to help you solve?

Comment: Meanwhile, try gorillaz: http://gorillaplayer.com/

Comment: I can use XAML previewer on Visual Studio but it still need a Mac coneection.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E7p2p8PK55I

Answer (score 3):

Using the latest version of Xamarin you can use the following steps:

Use the View > Other Windows > Xamarin.Forms Previewer menu in Visual Studio to open the preview window.

Comment: I couldn't find Xamarin.Forms Previewer in the Other Windows menu (though I have in the past?) but I was able to click the design buttons in the bottom right of the .xaml file pane to show the previewer. I believe you can also just drag the right edge of the xaml pane to reveal it.

Comment: Looks like this issue is known https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/312879/xamarin-forms-previewer-missing-in-last-update-158.html

Answer (score 1):

The Xamarin.Forms Previewer is there on Windows (it has been for a few years), but it now contains several improvements in Visual Studio 2019, many focused on making it more reliable.

To show the Previewer, click the design buttons on the bottom right of the .xaml file pane, like chucky mentioned. It's no longer under View > Other Windows, instead now using the same split pane tabbed UI used by the UWP/WPF designers.

See here for more on how to use the Previewer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-previewer/?tabs=vswin&pivots=windows

Comment: UPDATE: As of Visual Studio 16.9 / Visual Studio for Mac 8.9, the Previewer is removed as a feature. Instead you should use Hot Reload, which in most cases is a much better way to preview and update UI.

Comment: How can i view the UWP in different devices and screens?